# How to clear keyboard buffer from stale messages

Tags: winforms, keyboard, buffer, flush

My WinForms application has a button. This button has accelerator key (e.g. Alt+L). When button is pressed I handle the Click event and disable UI to prevent further button clicks until processing is finished. However, when accelerator key is pressed using keyboard those keystrokes are queued and get processed as soon as UI is enabled again. I don't want this. My question is how to clear/flush keyboard buffer?

If I use KeyPress or KeyDown to eat those characters I don't know when they have been received. I only want to suppress old/stale messages that arrived when I was still processing first Click event.

Comment: You *disable* the button and the keystrokes manage to push it? Try [`Application.DoEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) before re-enabling the button.

Comment: sounds like work you are doing might want to run on it's own thread to free up the user interface thread and keep the message pump going. Application.DoEvents might help. But another thread seems like a good idea too.

Comment: @madmik3: Agreed about creating a new thread. `Application.DoEvents` is somewhat of a hack. Multithreading is the more elegant solution. @Jacob: But you first need to confirm that UI blocking is indeed the problem. It's not clear from the question that you're doing everything else correctly.

Comment: @Cody: Maybe the fact that UI is disabled is not relevant. What I see is that if the user types faster than application can handle or it can't process the events, the keystrokes are queued for later processing. I don't want this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed your theory of the problem  is consistent with that proposed by both myself and madmik3 in the comment exchange above. The amount of work your application is doing on the UI thread is effectively blocking it from processing other events, including keystrokes by the user. Those are getting queued for later execution whenever your application finishes its time-consuming foreground task. Those are the perils of a modern-day, pre-emptive multitasking OS. Of course, without posting your actual code, the best I or anyone else can do is speculate about what the problem is, given our experience.

The quick check to confirm that this is actually the case is to toss [`Application.DoEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) into your processing loop. That will allow the OS to handle the keystrokes immediately, which will all fail because the button has been disabled. (`Click` events, whether initiated by the mouse or keyboard shortcuts, are not raised for a `Button` control that has its `Enabled` property set to "False".) This is the closest you'll get to anything like "flushing the buffers". I doubt you're receiving `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` events anyway until after whatever long-running task has completed.

If that fixes the problem, the long-term solution is to spawn a new thread and perform whatever processing you need to do there, instead of on your UI thread. This will prevent you from blocking your UI thread, and, assuming the `Button` control is correctly disabled, cause the keystrokes to get thrown away because the button they "click" is in a non-clickable state. The simplest way to create a new thread is using the [`BackgroundWorker` component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). The documentation contains a pretty good example.